# Error with TFS Build

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild, build-automation

I'm new to TFS and I'm trying to setup an automated build that will run each time there is a check in. I added a NuGet Installer and a Visual Studio Build steps but it looks like neither step is being executed. I tried disabling all steps to attempt to run a build that does nothing but still get the same error about a bin.rar file. This a fairly simple MVC project that should work with all the default settings. I've looked everywhere and have not found anything with a similar error.

I have also tried removing all the build steps and queued a new build but got the same error. There is no reference to bin.rar in the SLN, csproj, or config files.

[Error on TFS build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1uEj.png)

[Error in the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fUQX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new agent and a new build definition. Everything worked with the default setting and I didn't make any changes to the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clear bro, it is an **authentication problem**. make sure you have the required **permissions** before making the build. by going to

```
Build definition -> right hand click-> security-> build administrators -> Administer build permissions inherited allow.
```

[image]

Comment: I checked the permissions as you suggested but everything looks OK there. There was no warning and I looked in all the other options. My account is a TFS administrator. I set the build to run after each check which works but it fails immediately. I did find two references to bin.rar in the SLN file and removed them but the error persists.